# PEAR on PHP 7.2 on Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, pear

On a clean Windows installation I installed `PHP 7.2` with `Nginx` which works fine, both via `Nginx` as on the commandline. Now, I also want to install `PEAR` but that will output som `PHP` errors which don't fully know why the happen.

Bellow the full output of the command `php .\go-pear.phar` which I got from the official documentation page http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php.

```
Name of configuration file [C:\WINDOWS\pear.ini] : $prefix

Below is a suggested file layout for your new PEAR installation.  To
change individual locations, type the number in front of the
directory.  Type 'all' to change all of them or simply press Enter to
accept these locations.

 1. Installation base ($prefix)                   : C:\tools\php
 2. Temporary directory for processing            : C:\tools\php\tmp
 3. Temporary directory for downloads             : C:\tools\php\tmp
 4. Binaries directory                            : C:\tools\php
 5. PHP code directory ($php_dir)                 : C:\tools\php\pear
 6. Documentation directory                       : C:\tools\php\docs
 7. Data directory                                : C:\tools\php\data
 8. User-modifiable configuration files directory : C:\tools\php\cfg
 9. Public Web Files directory                    : C:\tools\php\www
10. System manual pages directory                 : C:\tools\php\man
11. Tests directory                               : C:\tools\php\tests
12. Name of configuration file                    : C:\tools\php
13. Path to CLI php.exe                           : C:\tools\php

1-13, 'all' or Enter to continue:
Beginning install...
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::set() in phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start.php:322
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start/CLI.php(72): PEAR_Start->doInstall()
#1 phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/index.php(5): PEAR_Start_CLI->run()
#2 C:\tools\php\go-pear.phar(1271): require_once('phar://C:/tools...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start.php on line 322

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::set() in phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start.php:322
Stack trace:
#0 phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start/CLI.php(72): PEAR_Start->doInstall()
#1 phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/index.php(5): PEAR_Start_CLI->run()
#2 C:\tools\php\go-pear.phar(1271): require_once('phar://C:/tools...')
#3 {main}
  thrown in phar://C:/tools/php/go-pear.phar/PEAR/Start.php on line 322
```

Comment: Any reason for using PEAR? Long live the [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: @MichaelZukowski yes, needed the MailParse extension http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php which depends on PEAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually on a page of the documentation:
https://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.php

`Windows 7 will not allow the installation script to write to c:\windows\pear.ini. It gives the "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PEAR_Error::set()" error. Change the location of the configuration files (#11) to someplace writable, complete the installation, then copy the contents into c:\windows\pear.ini.`

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution to this is: Run cmd as administrator.